# How can I observe Activity Live data class in Fragment Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, fragment

I have been trying to observe this code in a fragment but I am not getting it. If I use it on a normal activity it works but on fragment it brings errors.

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
private lateinit var checkNetworkConnection: CheckNetworkConnection
private lateinit var internetLayout: RelativeLayout
private lateinit var noInternetLayout: RelativeLayout
private lateinit var tryAgainButton: Button
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

}
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    internetLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.internetLayout)
    noInternetLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.noInternetLayout)
    tryAgainButton = view.findViewById(R.id.try_again_button)
    tryAgainButton.setOnClickListener {
        callNetworkConnection()
    }
    callNetworkConnection()
    val url = ""
    val web = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.webView) as WebView
    web.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    web.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
    web.settings.useWideViewPort = true
    web.settings.builtInZoomControls = true
    web.settings.pluginState = WebSettings.PluginState.ON
    web.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
    web.loadUrl(url)
}

private fun callNetworkConnection() {
    checkNetworkConnection = CheckNetworkConnection()
    checkNetworkConnection.observe(this,{ isConnected ->
        if (isConnected){
            internetLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            noInternetLayout.visibility = View.GONE
        } else {
            noInternetLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            internetLayout.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    })

}
```

}

This the error I get:

> None of the following functions can be called with the arguments
> supplied:  public constructor CheckNetworkConnection(application:
> Application) defined in com.oreal.ng.CheckNetworkConnection public
> constructor CheckNetworkConnection(connectivityManager:
> ConnectivityManager) defined in com.oreal.ng.CheckNetworkConnection

Please help me please

Answer (score 1):

Give `viewLifecycleOwner` a try instead of `this`.

Comment: Can you explain using code boss?

Comment: If 'this' (currently Fragment) is passed as a parameter of LiveData, in some cases, Fragment is not destroyed, but a new observer is registered and multiple observers are called. I tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `this` try using `requireContext()`